# Dark mode switch doesn't work using navbarPage - shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app for which I'd like to add a dark mode switch. I've managed to do that after some research online but as I was trying to implement this bit of code in my app I encountered issues. I have been trying several things on a simpler app to try to identify what causes the switch to not work and I came to the conclusion that adding a navbarPage to my app is what makes it crash.
Below is a simple example:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(bslib)

ui <- fluidPage(
  theme=bs_theme(),
  # navbarPage("TITLE",
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
                 numericInput("num", label = h3("Numeric input"), value = 1),
                 materialSwitch(inputId = "mode", label = icon("moon"), right=TRUE,status = "success")),
               mainPanel(verbatimTextOutput("value")) #fin main panel
             ) 
       # )
)


server <- function(input, output,session) {
  observe({
    if(input$mode==TRUE)
      session$setCurrentTheme(bs_theme_update(theme, bootswatch = "superhero"))
    if(input$mode==FALSE)
      session$setCurrentTheme(bs_theme_update(theme, bootswatch = "default"))
  })
  
  output$value <- renderPrint({ input$num })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

As long as the navbar line and corresponding ")" is considered as a comment it works fine but as soon as I uncomment these two lines I get this error:

```
Warning: Navigation containers expect a collection of `bslib::nav()`/`shiny::tabPanel()`s and/or `bslib::nav_menu()`/`shiny::navbarMenu()`s. Consider using `header` or `footer` if you wish to place content above (or below) every panel's contents.

Listening on http://--.--
Warning: Error in : session$setCurrentTheme() cannot be used to change the Bootstrap version from  to 4. Try using `bs_theme(version = 4)` for initial theme.
  47: stop
  46: session$setCurrentTheme
  45: observe [C:/Users/user/Documents/shiny/SHINY-APP/app4.R#23]
  44: <observer>
   1: runApp
```

I am very new to shiny despite being familiar with R but I really don't understand this error. I have been trying to find answers in the documentation associated to the different functions I'm using as well as in previously asked questions on SO but I haven't been able to fix this yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you !

Comment: I copied your code and gives me an error: 
Warning: Error in is_bs_theme: object 'theme' not found
  [No stack trace available]

I changed the `theme` inside `bs_theme_update` to `bs_theme()` and worked.

Comment: Then, I uncommented the navbarPage lines and got this error:

Warning message:
Navigation containers expect a collection of `bslib::nav()`/`shiny::tabPanel()`s and/or `bslib::nav_menu()`/`shiny::navbarMenu()`s. Consider using `header` or `footer` if you wish to place content above (or below) every panel's contents.

Comment: @Pabort Thank you for your comments ! I have the same warnings before the error when I uncomment the navbarPage lines (I forgot to include the warning in my post, I will edit it). My understanding of header/footer was that it is used to place an object (for exemple the material switch) above of below all sidebarPanel and mainPanel. I have tried putting the switch in footer but it doesnt fix the error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the theme both in the fluidPage and the navbarPage (maybe you can get rid of fluidPage, didn't test it)

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(bslib)

ui <- fluidPage(
  theme=bs_theme(version = 4, bootswatch = "default"),
  navbarPage("TITLE",
             theme=bs_theme(version = 4, bootswatch = "default"),
             tabPanel("Tab",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          numericInput("num", label = h3("Numeric input"), value = 1),
                          materialSwitch(inputId = "mode", label = icon("moon"),
                                         right=TRUE,status = "success")),
                        mainPanel(verbatimTextOutput("value")) #fin main panel
                      )
             )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output,session) {

  
  observe(session$setCurrentTheme(
    if(isTRUE(input$mode)){
      bs_theme(bootswatch = "superhero")
    } else {
      bs_theme(bootswatch = "default")
    }
  ))
  
  output$value <- renderPrint({ input$num })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This is because navbarPage uses by default version 3 of bootstrap and doesn't inherit whatever version you use on the upper div